# Spark: PartitionBy, change output file name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Currently, when I use the `paritionBy()` to write to HDFS:

```
DF.write.partitionBy("id")
```

I will get output structure looking like (which is the default behaviour):

```
../id=1/

../id=2/

../id=3/
```

I would like a structure looking like:

```
../a/

../b/

../c/
```

such that:

```
if id = 1, then a
if id = 2, then b

.. etc
```

Is there a way to change the filename output? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use Spark's `partitionBy` to achieve this.

Instead, you have to break your `DataFrame` into its component partitions, and save them one by one, like so:

```
base = ord('a') - 1
for id in range(1, 4):
    DF.filter(DF['id'] == id).write.save("..." + chr(base + id))
}
```

Alternatively, you can write the entire dataframe using Spark's `partitionBy` facility, and then manually rename the partitions using HDFS APIs.

Comment: which one its more efficient?, I'm learning spark and it seems that `for` loops in pyspark are considered as different stages, so that makes the process way much slower than using `partitionBy` and then apply some OS re-organization solution