# How to edit end of an s3 object keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

```
inputfile='s3a://storename/stores.csv'
output_file='s3a://storename/newstores.parquet'
```

Created a dataframe consists of three columns `Id`, `Type`, `Size`.

```
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(inputfile)
```

created another dataframe and selected two columns `Type`, `Size` from `df`.

```
df1=df.select("Type","Size")
df1.show()

Type     Size

A         5847

A         9887

B         9873
```

Writing that into `s3` in parquet, partitioned by column `Type`:

```
df1.write.partitionBy("Type").format("parquet").save(output_file).
```

My partitioned file names object keys are showing as below:

```
Type=A
Type=B
```

Is there any way that we can edit so that my `s3` object keys can be seen as below? I am new to `spark` and `AWS`. Thanks.

```
A_file.parquet

B_file.parquet
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: PartitionBy, change output file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154696/spark-partitionby-change-output-file-name)